# change the icon after authorization

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

How to change the icon after authorization?
before registration should be the input icon `<div class="auth_icon">`. After the user registered the icon should be changed to another block `<div class="icForRegistrUsers">`. [link to the project on GitHub](https://github.com/vitarunaeva/vlgplace.git)

```html
 <div class="auth_icon">
                <a href="#popup-auth" class="js-popup-open"><img src="./public/images/icons/enter.svg" height="35px" width="35px" alt="authorization_icon" title="authorization"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="icForRegistrUsers">
                <a href="/profile"><img src="./public/images/icons/avatar.svg" height="35px" width="35px" alt="avatar_icon" title="profile"></a>
                <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-logout">Logout</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: you could run a JS function which changes the class in the CSS. That should work out.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple ways to do this and depends on some stuffs.

1. If those 2 blocks are the same only the classes are different you
   can remove the old class and add the new one in your js script in
   the authorization success call.
2. If the 2 blocks are different you can swap the display property for the 2 divs. Before authorization `<div class="auth_icon">` has display block, and `<div class="icForRegistrUsers">` has display none, and after registration `<div class="auth_icon">` has display none and `<div class="icForRegistrUsers">` is block

Comment: i don't know how to implement a check on a user's authorization to make the change icons

Answer (score 0):

**In Express 4**
Install the [favicon middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-favicon) and then do:

```
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico'));
Or better, using the path module:

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname,'public','images','favicon.ico')));
(note that this solution will work in express 3 apps as well)
```

**In Express 3**
According to the API, [.favicon](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/favicon.html) accepts a location parameter:

```
app.use(express.favicon("public/images/favicon.ico"));
```

Most of the time, you might want this (as vsync suggested):

```
app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico'));
```

Or better yet, use the path module (as Druska suggested):

```
app.use(express.favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public','images','favicon.ico')));
```